# On deleting a button how to add again back to same position angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

In the below plunkr, after i click on add button it is added to the below scope items and it is removed from the above scope items. I would like to know when user removes from below scope items how can i add again back to the above scope at same index point from where it is removed. plunkr link - https://plnkr.co/edit/EFqMKkC4wMsjYmg64n7q?p=preview

html-

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tree.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body data-ng-app="testApp" data-ng-controller="button">

<hr>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-click="save()">SaveFilter</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-Default" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-click="delete()">Delete</button>

<button ng-repeat="name in listofSystems" style="border-radius: 25px; outline-color:#fff;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="{{name.name}}" ng-click="addSystemsButton($event,$index)">{{name.name}}   +</button>

<hr>
<p><strong>Selected Systems</strong></p>
<button ng-repeat="name in listofSystemsAdded" style="border-radius: 25px; outline-color:#fff;" type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="removeSelectedSystemsButton($index)">{{name.name}}    x</button> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can all be done using angular filter(s) and not change original array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add it back to listofSystems, like you do when you press a "system".

I have updated your plunker:

```
  $scope.removeSelectedSystemsButton = function(ind) {
    console.log(ind);
    $scope.listofSystems.push($scope.listofSystemsAdded[ind]);
    $scope.listofSystemsAdded.splice(ind, 1)
  };
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/oeBOY1Va9LXDJUCSWaxw?p=preview

Comment: is there any way that i can add it to the same position from where it is removed in the above scope items?

Comment: Yes, you can use this method: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ni805uhlMHOxxzr5VO1O?p=preview

Comment: Looking for the same output. Thanks!